# How to get names of mysql tables, columns and their types?

Tags: mysql, .net, vb.net

To improve the ease of use, I want my mysql connection wrapper class to automatically determine the type of command properties. I'm assuming the information I need is available though the connector api but I've no clue how, is there a command to get the names and types of columns?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For table name:

```
SELECT TABLE_NAME
FROM information_schema.TABLES 
WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = 'your database name'
```

Or

```
SHOW TABLES IN db_name
```

For Columns:

```
SELECT COLUMN_NAME, DATA_TYPE, IS_NULLABLE, COLUMN_DEFAULT
  FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
  WHERE table_name = 'tbl_name'
  [AND table_schema = 'db_name']
```

Choose fields as per your requirements.

Answer (score 1):

Many ways, many columns, pick and choose:

```
SELECT column_name, data_type,is_nullable,character_maximum_length 
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS 
WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'course' and TABLE_SCHEMA='so_gibberish'; 

+-------------+-----------+-------------+--------------------------+
| column_name | data_type | is_nullable | character_maximum_length |
+-------------+-----------+-------------+--------------------------+
| course_id   | varchar   | NO          |                        8 |
| title       | varchar   | YES         |                       50 |
| dept_name   | varchar   | YES         |                       20 |
| credits     | decimal   | YES         |                     NULL |
+-------------+-----------+-------------+--------------------------+
```